# App getting force closed on Back Key pressed

Tags: android, android-contacts, vcf-vcard

I am working on a VCard application. here I have started Default Contacts activity(Address Book).

Now, the flow of application is like this,

- User Launches the application.
- Default contact book is opened.
- User selects a contact from the list and then a Vcard of the selected contact is created.

Now, when the user presses `Back Button` without selecting any contact, the app gets force closed.

I have overidden `BackKeyPress()` event, but its not working. The app is still getting force closed.

I am posting the code for reference,

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        Log.d("In Oncreate", "Activity Result");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
         //preventing default implementation previous to android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Back Pressed", 5000).show();
             finish();
         return true;
         }
         return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

      switch (reqCode) {
        case (1) :
            counter = "Yes";
    Log.d("My Tag", data.getExtras().keySet().toString());
    name_selected = data.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.shortcut.NAME");
    Log.d("My Tag", name_selected));
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BusinessCardActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("name", name_selected);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
       }
    }
}
```

Logcat Errors:-

```
12-17 18:41:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(23456): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 18:41:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(23456): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.android.business/com.android.business.ReadContacts}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-17 18:41:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(23456):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
12-17 18:41:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(23456):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2578)
12-17 18:41:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(23456):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-17 18:41:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(23456):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:961)
12-17 18:41:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(23456):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-17 18:41:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(23456):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-17 18:41:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(23456):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3729)
12-17 18:41:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(23456):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-17 18:41:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(23456):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-17 18:41:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(23456):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
12-17 18:41:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(23456):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:632)
12-17 18:41:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(23456):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-17 18:41:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(23456): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-17 18:41:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(23456):    at com.android.business.ReadContacts.onActivityResult(ReadContacts.java:133)
12-17 18:41:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(23456):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
12-17 18:41:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(23456):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
```

Here the user is supposed to select a contact from the list, but if the user presses back button without selecting any contact, the app gets force closed.

Comment: hmm, let me post the logcat errors.

Comment: I guess the issue is in line where you have included **Do some operations on the selected contact** . So do show the code

Comment: you don't test resultCode. I assume you do some operations (which for some odd reason you decided were not relevant to your question (while a quick look (which obviously you failed to take) at the stacktrace would have told you otherwise)) that include working on the receive data, ensue most likely an NPE or a SIOOBE or something.

Comment: com.android.business.ReadContacts.onActivityResult(ReadContacts.java:133) which line is that?

Comment: is there any code `// Do some operations on the selected contact` here in `onActivityResult()` ?

Comment: I ahve edited my code and added the operations that I'm performing on selecting contact.

Comment: @Nunu : That line is, where I'm getting the name of the selected contact. It is failing because is no seleceted contact at all.

Comment: You should probably rephrase your question. The error has nothing todo with the back pressed but with your onActivityResult.

Comment: Yes, its absolutely failing, because I've no selected contact at all, when the back key is pressed. but how should i hanlde this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your OnActivityResult() do this..

```
 @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

  switch (reqCode) {
    case (1) :
     if (data != null && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        counter = "Yes";
    // Do some operations on the selected contact
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: @user370305 If the user presses the back button, you'll get a RESULT_CANCELED, so this answer is the correct one.

Comment: yes, this answer has worked. Now when back button is pressed, the previous activity is opened(which has passed the intent to open contacts activity. However, I have used RESULT_CANCELED as said by @Shyish to track when the user escapes from the app. thank you both of you

Answer (score 3):

use this...

```
     @Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

  switch (reqCode) {
    case 1:
    if(data!=null&&resultCode==RESULT_OK){


        counter = "Yes";
Log.d("My Tag", data.getExtras().keySet().toString());
name_selected = data.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.shortcut.NAME");
Log.d("My Tag", name_selected));
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BusinessCardActivity.class);
i.putExtra("name", name_selected);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I have overidden BackKeyPress() event, but its not working. The app is still getting force closed.
```

Because the `backKeyPressed()` event responds to `Default Contacts activity(Address Book)`. Not to your Android Application's Activity.

As I seen your code for `onActivityResult()` and **Without any logcat errors** I think this crash may be happen at `Default Contacts activity(Address Book)` side not at your application side. Also You have to check for is `Default Contacts activity(Address Book)` is handled any `Intent` (Resulted Intent) for `onActivityResult()` as respond purpose to other application.

So **logcat errors** will be more helpful over here.

**EDIT:**

**Yeah As I Have a doubt,** Your resulted **data** is `NULL`

before doing operation on `Intent`  just check whether `data` is **null** or not,

```
if(data != null)
{
 Log.d("My Tag", data.getExtras().keySet().toString());
    name_selected = data.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.shortcut.NAME");
    Log.d("My Tag", name_selected));
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BusinessCardActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("name", name_selected);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: I think you are right, because the app only gets force closed, when back pressed from contacts activity. I'll post the code, where I'm performing operation on the selected contact.

Comment: Both this and @Pradeep answers are the really good approach, because you should check if the result code is the correct (RESULT_OK) and also check if the data received isn't null (that should not happen, but worth it).

Comment: I found that it is failing because of the **name_selected**. It comes out to be null when the back button is pressed.

Comment: @user370305 yes u r right i must do intent null check also.. Thank u I updated my Answer

Answer (score 1):

Your application gets force closed due to a NullPointerException thrown in line 133 in your onActivityResult method. Check if the result is valid and put some try catch in there.

```
12-17 18:41:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(23456): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-17 18:41:09.399: E/AndroidRuntime(23456):    at com.android.business.ReadContacts.onActivityResult(ReadContacts.java:133)
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you managing the case that there's no selected contact? If the user press back and no contact is selected, in your onActivityResult you should handle that the "contact" is null.

Comment: I don't understand why I get a negative in my answer. However, check @njzk2 comment, which is the same as I said and I think is the correct answer.